# UICollectionViewCell content change when scrolled up/down

Tags: ios, swift, uicollectionview

I am working on an UICollectionView where I have to rotate a label in the UICollectionViewCell. Before scrolling up/down it looks perfect. But once I scrolled the UICollectionView the label retransform to the status it was before. 
Before Scrolling :

[image]

After Scrolling :

[image]

The code I used :

`cell.lblName?.frame = CGRect(x: 15, y: (((self.collectionView?.frame.size.height)!/3)/2) - 20, width: cell.frame.size.height , height: 40)
        cell.lblName?.backgroundColor = UIColor.red
        cell.lblName?.transform = CGAffineTransform(rotationAngle: CGFloat((Double.pi/2) * 3))`

Comment: I think it is AutoLayout Issue.

Comment: @NavodaP Where did you place this code? Do you use xib for cell or create it programmatically?

Comment: @AbhishekMitra : I didn't use AutoLayout here as I'm going to change it anyway

Comment: @trungduc - Inside 'cellForItemAt' method , In the storyboard, inside the uicollectionview itself. I created a class for IBoutlets and called them inside the uicollectionviewcell

Comment: I think label is rotated more than 1 time. It's the problem. You should check and make it rotate only one time. Create a subclass of `UICollectionViewCell` and put this code inside `awakeFromNib` method can resolve your problem

Comment: Since you are rotating able inside cellForItemAtIndexPath, every time cell reloads lable is rotated again and again.You can take a bool variable in array from where you are showing your data and set to true first time and rotate it only once

Comment: Correct! the label has been rotated more than once, which was the issue. Putting the code inside 'awakeFromNib' worked!
Thanks a lot all!

Answer (score 2):

Well, I did test for my self and its working perfectly, what i have done is

```
cell.label.transform = CGAffineTransform(rotationAngle: CGFloat.pi / 2)
```

and i did use`Autolayout`, and it working as expected.

Follow the image bellow:

Cell ImageView and UILabel with Autolayout

[image]

[image]

[image]

Hope this help you.
Thanks

**EDITED**

Use `cell.label.transform = CGAffineTransform(rotationAngle: -CGFloat.pi / 2)` for your type rotation.

Comment: nice solution!!

Answer (score 1):

[image]    You just need rotate view which are taken inside the cell.

```
Write this code snippet in cellForItem dataSource method of collection view.

cell.viewDemo.transform = CGAffineTransform(rotationAngle: -CGFloat.pi / 2)
```